# Privacy Policy Updates (Feb 2020)

Tags: discussion, legal, privacy

We want to share with you that we have updated our Privacy Policy to keep up with the ever evolving data privacy laws and regulations concerning our global community of users and our sites.  We also took the opportunity to review and remove language describing data usage that we currently do not apply, and data usages we have no plans to do in the future as our business evolves.  We want to make sure to limit the scope of data usage included in our Privacy Policy, out of respect for you all and your privacy.

As our business grows, we have created a new policy structure with one foundational, summary Privacy Policy that applies across all our products and services, as well as product-specific sections of our Privacy Policy that describes how our Privacy Policy applies in the context of each of our products. We did this to provide greater transparency about what we do with your data when interacting with each of our products.  We plan to keep this framework going forward for consistency and clarity.  We also changed and added language within the Privacy Policy to be more clear and specific about how your data is used.

High level summary of the changes:

- We’ve restructured the [privacy policy pages](/legal/privacy-policy) so that the language is clearer and more transparent
- There is a supplemental “Privacy Policy Notice” for each product area: [Public Network](/legal/privacy-policy/public-network), [Talent & Jobs](/legal/privacy-policy/talent), and Teams: [Basic](/legal/privacy-policy/teams-basic), [Business](/legal/privacy-policy/teams-business), and [Enterprise](/legal/privacy-policy/teams-enterprise).
- We’ve removed descriptions of data usage that no longer apply to our products and which we found we never applied to your data.
- We’ve updated the language to comply with evolving data privacy laws and requirements.

Our legal, community, product, and engineering teams worked diligently to make sure the new language and structure create clear, understandable policies.  Going forward, we will not maintain the “Plain English” version of our Privacy Policy, to avoid trying to interpret policy for you all.  That was never our intent with previous “Plain English” narratives, but the expanding and evolving set of privacy laws across countries and states only makes this that much more difficult.

As always, you have control over the data you share on our platform. As a reminder, you can [view and update your profile settings here](/users/edit/current) and [control email preferences here](/users/email/settings/current).

Comment: I can't help but noticing that it refers to the Stack Overflow Network rather than the Stack Exchange Network

Comment: Psst - there is a "persomal" typo in one of the headings.

Comment: @BryanKrause: Good eye. For further reference, the heading "How is your persomal data collected?" appears on only the Public Network and Talent subpages.

Comment: Is there a diff somewhere? E.g. GitHub keeps their policies in a public git repository to keep changes transparent.

Comment: From the privacy policy: "You may revoke our permission to collect some of this data, including your location and browser information through your Account Settings, but this may limit functionality in some cases." - where? Is it the activity data setting?

Comment: Aren't you legally required to notify users of all privacy policy changes? This post is not even featured!

Answer (score 43):

One part of the policy I can't interpret as a non-lawyer are the exact restrictions and terms for third-party ads. As far as I can tell some ads on the network run with sufficient privilege to potentially do anything that is possible with client-side Javascript. And at least one example was found that does seem to perform rather extensive fingerprinting of the browser environment.

As far as I can tell from the privacy policy ads are allowed to serve cookies. I can't really find any other information on what they can do and what they are not allowed to do. What are the actual policies for ads that run on the SE network?

Comment: Anything related to our ads policy can be found in the links of the original post. We are working on sharing additional thoughts on our approach to advertising on the network. That will come in the near future.

Answer (score 25):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I know, that there is the option to make a GDPR request through an internal interface (https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/gdpr/request). I did not find that link, when reading through the privacy policy for the network and the general one.

I did find it by going to "Data subjects (You)", which seems less intuitive, when one is looking for a GDPR-request link.

Instead there were several mentions of sending an email to privacy@stackoverflow.com. Could there be added a link to the request interface, please?